# golang datastore struct: keeping field unique and required

Tags: google-app-engine, go, struct, google-cloud-datastore

Im wondering how to best guarantee that a field is unique and isn't saved to the datastore if it isn't. Also that it should be required. I am using this field as stringID and need it to be unique. I know that I can simply try to get an entity by this field and see if it exists and build a logic around it. But is there a simpler way like declaring in your struct that the field should be unique and/or required? Like the mockup below.

```
type Car struct {
    Regnr  string "required" "unique"
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: It's not possible with datastore. But you can workaround it by additional Kind: https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/_modules/webapp2_extras/appengine/auth/models.html#Unique

Comment: Okey thanks! Will have a look

Answer (score 0):

From the Datastore API:

> By default, for struct pointers, all properties are potentially
>   indexed, and the property name is the same as the field name (and
>   hence must start with an upper case letter). Fields may have a
>   `datastore:"name,options"` tag. The tag name is the property name,
>   which must be one or more valid Go identifiers joined by ".", but may
>   start with a lower case letter. An empty tag name means to just use
>   the field name. A "-" tag name means that the datastore will ignore
>   that field. If options is "noindex" then the field will not be
>   indexed. If the options is "" then the comma may be omitted. **There are
>   no other recognized options.**

Not possible to set those type of tags with Datastore.